# When running "flutter pub get", where exactly is the package hosted?

Tags: flutter, dart

Asking this question because corporate internet blocked my "flutter pub get" command, I'm getting this:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in ProjectA...              
Handshake error in client (OS Error: 

CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354))
```

Tried with my own internet at home and it works fine.

I need to know the location of where the package is hosted so I can ask IT to whitelist it.

Answer (score 0):

The packages you get on pub.dev should come from https://pub.dartlang.org